Is "Protagonist's family gets killed by dark forces" an original idea?
As the title suggests, is "Protagonist's family gets killed by dark forces" an original idea? It was something I had originally conceived.  However, I realized that Harry Potter has a very similar premise.
In my story, the Protagonist's family gets murdered by alternate-history Nazis, which builds his grudge towards them.
I'm sorry if such questions aren't permissible here, I'm pretty new to writing in general.

It's a common trope. See e.g. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FamilyExtermination or https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouKilledMyFather.

Harry Potter, Star Wars (at least in Episode 4), Princess Bride ("Hello. My name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father. Prepare to die."), Batman, Spiderman (most prominently with uncle Ben, but Peter Parker was already an orphan at that point), Magneto from X-Men (death by the Nazi), the Lion King, the Dresden Files (Harry's father is implied to have been killed by some enemy of his mother), Supernatural. Just off the top of my head. The real question is - why does it even matter whether it's original?

It's good you add a personal reason why the protagonist would hold a grudge against literal genocidal nazis.... since modern readers often struggle with identifying hyperbolic evil for its own sake.

It's a common trope. Pops up over and over again. See VLAZ's comment.
I see that one of the tags you label the question with is "plagiarism". If you're concerned that you might be accused of plagiarising some particular work (for example, Harry Potter) if you use this trope, don't worry. This is a classic trope that has been done so many times that using it once more won't raise any such flags unless you make the details of the scene very reminiscent. On the other hand, it won't get you praised for your original and unique idea either, because it really isn't.

And while the killed parents make a lot of sense – because having part of your family extinguished by some enemy has been a common experience throughout human history –, the "alternate-history Nazis" are probably the most stale and lazy trope of all. @mvogel, please come up with a more interesting antagonist.

Is the idea totally original? No. Many horror stories are about the hero's family being killed by "dark forces".
Does that make your story unoriginal? No. When boiled down to a broad summary like that, few stories could be said to be totally original. There are many, many stories with subjects like, "a man and a woman fall in love, run into obstacles, but get together in the end". Or, "a brilliant detective solves a complex crime". Or, "an adventurer goes on a quest to find a valuable object". Etc.
I often hear novice writers fret, "Will people say that my story is just a rip-off of 'Star Wars' because my story is also about a war in outer space?" Or whatever. No. If you're story copies many elements of the other story, if there are whole scenes that look like you just copied someone else's story, changed the characters' names, and called it your own, yes, you will be ridiculed for copying the other story. But if your story is only similar in some very broad, general sense -- it's also about a brilliant detective or it's also about ghosts or whatever -- then no, saying it's copied from the other story would be a silly criticism.

It's not an original idea, but that doesn't mean you can't make it your own!
This trope is one of the most commonly used tropes for building a hero's character arc (it's in Harry Potter, Hunger Games, Series of Unfortunate Events, and more). But the special thing that each of these books/series does is they put their own spin on it!
If you're concerned about plagiarism or not having an original and fun new idea, don't sweat it. I have so far not read a book where alternate-history Nazis kill someone's parents, so you should be all good.
Hope this helped!
